# Add JPanel from other Class to JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jbutton

I would like to add a JPanel from another class to a JPanel:

```
class FirstPanel extends JPanel
{
private JButton button;

FirstPanel()
{
    setLayout(null);
    setVisible(true);

    button = new JButton();

    button.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
    button.setFocusPainted(false);
    button.setIcon(new ImageIcon(SecondPanel.class.getResource(filePath)));
    button.setBackground(bgColor);
    button.setForeground(Color.white);
    button.setVisible(true);

    Border emptyBorder = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder();
    button.setBorder(emptyBorder);

    add(button);

    ButtonActionHandler buttonActionHandler = new ButtonActionHandler();

}


public class ButtonActionHandler implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        setVisible(true);
        add(new SecondJPanel());

        new SecondJPanel().setVisible(true);
    }
} }
```

And this is my Second JPanel:

```
class SecondPanel extends JPanel
{
private JButton button;
private JLabel titleLabel;

SecondPanel()
{

    setLayout(null);
    setVisible(true);

    button = new JButton();

    button.setBounds(100, 200, 100, 200);
    button.setFocusPainted(false);
    button.setIcon(new ImageIcon(SecondPanel.class.getResource(filePath)));
    button.setBackground(bgColor);
    button.setForeground(Color.white);
    button.setVisible(true);

    Border emptyBorder = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder();
    button.setBorder(emptyBorder);

    add(button);
}
```

}

The Launching of the First Panel through a JFrame (from another class) works, however the adding of the second JPanel to the first one doesn't.

Any help is really appreciated

Comment: You want composition here: Add both JPanels to a single JFrame.  You'll need a layout manager.

Comment: So, I need to put everything in one JFrame Class?

Comment: That's how I would do it.  That allows you to compose a complex page out of simpler JPanels.  I would recommend reading up on dependency injection.  You can vary your handlers easily with constructor injection.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the quick reply :)

Comment: And another question, should I rather continue with Java Swing or start with JavaFX?

Comment: I don't know what your requirements are.  You seem new to Java.  Swing has been around for a very long time.  Learn it, get comfortable, pick up JavaFX if you have a need and desire.  Most people have gone in the direction of web services and browser based UIs, available on desktops and mobile devices.  Swing and JavaFX are 1990s/2000s vintage technologies.

Comment: Well, I am actually coming from about two years Android programming, and there we have each layout in an extra Activity class from default, so that's the reason why I wanted to have each Panel in an extra class. The current thing is for a school project. Well, I wasn't very eager to now having to do with an kind of "old" technology. Anyways, would you still recommend Java Swing for "experienced" people rather than JavaFX?

Comment: I would expect an Android programmer with two years of experience to have no trouble picking this up.  Each JPanel should be in a separate class.  Your JFrame composes them at the end.  I don't recommend things.  You can make up your own mind.  The world has gone in the direction of simple and open: that's the web.  HTTP would be my preference.

Comment: Oh, well I actually started off with having the JFrame calling the JPanel but then I wanted to try out if it would also work by adding a JPanel to another JPanel. Anyways, thank you very much

Comment: "however the adding of the second JPanel to the first one doesn't." - what is the desired result ? two `JPanel` side by side ? top and bottom ?  one covers the other ? Add a simple illustration to explain what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: Hello, well I am adding the `SecondPanel extends JPanel` with  `add(new SecondPanel());` In the mean time I've added a JOptionPane, which gets displayed. The rest of the JPanel however doesn't. But when I launch the programm with the SecondPanel everything gets displayed correctly. Before I posted this question I've tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12021249/adding-jpanel-from-another-class-to-jpanel-in-jframe and I think that it worked, but then it didn't anymore :/

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but you don't seem to be understanding what I am telling you.

Composition is your friend.

I would do it like this:

```
public class JPanel1 extends JPanel {

    private JButton button;

    public JPanel1(ActionListener buttonListener) {
       this.button = new Button("Push me");
       this.button.addActionListener(buttonListener);
       // do what's needed to add the button to the display.
    }
}

public class JPanel2 extends JPanel {

    private JButton button;

    public JPanel2(ActionListener buttonListener) {
       this.button = new Button("Push me");
       this.button.addActionListener(buttonListener);
       // do what's needed to add the button to the display.
    }
}

public class TwoPanelFrame extends JFrame {

    public TwoPanelFrame(JPanel p1, JPanel p2) {
        // add the two panels to your frame and display.
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, but how do I display JPanel2 when I click on a button in JPanel1?